# Api сервис возвращает ошибку авторизации/метода

Tags: php, api

```
$nonce=$time;
$post_data= 'method=Trade&pair='.$new_nopc.'&type=buy&rate='.$Sell*1.2.'&amount=1&nonce='.$nonce;
var_dump($post_data);
$sign = hash_hmac ('sha512',$post_data,$Secret) ;
$headers = array(
      "Key".$key, //ключ 
      "Sign".$sign  //с ключ
    );
// создание curl
    $ch = null;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://yobit.net/tapi/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , $headers);        
  //посылаем созданный запрос в API
    $res = curl_exec($ch);


    // проверяем ответ и закрываем curl
    if($res === false) {
        $e = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception('Could not get reply: '.$e);
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    //расшифровываем json в тип array()
    $result = json_decode($res, true);
    echo "<br>";

    ?>

$post_data="method=Trade&pair=eth_btc&type=buy&rate=0.0502776&amount=1&nonce=1703094504"
```

Сервис возвращает `json` с ошибкой

> array(2) { ["success"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(34) "invalid key, sign, method or nonce" }

Не знаю в чём ошибка, помогите пожалуйста.

Каждый запрос Trade API должен пройти аутентификацию.
Аутентификация происходит способом отправки следующих HTTP-заголовков:
Key - API-ключ, пример: `FAF816D16FFDFBD1D46EEF5D5B10D8A2`
Sign - цифровая подпись,
 POST-параметры (`?param0=val0 & ...& nonce=1`) подписанные секретным ключом с помощью `HMAC-SHA512`
Параметр `nonce` (минимум 1, максимум 2147483646) при каждом новом запросе должен быть больше значения из предыдущего запроса.
Для обнуления `nonce` необходимо создать новый ключ.

Comment: это сервис апи присылает такой джэйсон?

Comment: CURLOPT_POST попробуйте добавить. CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER вы точно правильно используете? они же скорее предназначены для заголовков сервера, а не паролей.

Comment: Добавлял CURLOPT_POST ничего не меняется. Джэйсон присылает этот сервис https://yobit.net/ru/api/

Comment: Все верно, для начала добавьте `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` потому что ваш cURL-запрос не понимает, что нужно отправлять данные методом `POST` и отправляет обычный `GET`-запрос.

Comment: может быть еще надо было так? $headers = array("Key: " . $key,   "Sign: " . $sign ); посмотрите как отправляются заголовки http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Да и так же добавьте `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` раз это HTTPS-запрос.

Comment: Всё равно ошибка авторизации.

Comment: обратите внимание Key Sign с большой буквы